# Puppet -> undefined method 'to_sym' for []:Array

Tags: ruby, puppet, statsd

this is my 10th day using puppet so sorry if there is not enough information.

I installed module 'statsd' from: https://forge.puppet.com/jdowning/statsd on my puppet-master and used it like in readme file.

```
class { 'statsd':
    backends                 => ['./backends/graphite'],
    graphiteHost             => "graphite-relay.dev.sizmdx.com",
    graphite_globalPrefix    => 'statsite',
    graphite_legacyNamespace => false, 
    stackdriver_sendTimerPercentiles => false,
    configfile => '/etc/statsd/localConfig.js'
}
```

I keep getting this error:

> Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Error from DataBinding 'hiera' while looking up 'statsd::librato_skipInternalMetrics': undefined method `to_sym' for []:Array on node beadmin-dev0-lior-cm-3f4gxw0f.sizmek
>   Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
>   Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run

We do have 'Heira' in the puppet project (altough I'm not familiar too much with that)
here the Heira.yaml:

```
:backends: 
  - yaml

:hierarchy:
  - client/%{clientcert}
  - roles/%{role}
  - environment/%{env}
  - global

:yaml: 
  :datadir: /opt/puppet/hiera
```

I google'd the error without any findings, any suggestions ?
if need more information please let me know.

thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the cause, without knowing more about your environment, but [interpolated values in hiera must be enclosed in quotes](https://docs.puppet.com/hiera/3.1/variables.html#interpolation-tokens). Your example hiera config does not have them in quotes.

Comment: I was able to re-create your circumstances (statsd module, manifest, and hiera config without quotes) and could not reproduce the error. Would it be possible for you to get further debug information (both client/server) as well as information on your environment (how you are executing Puppet, your hiera data etc...)?

Comment: do you have a hiera key somewhere starting with `:`? (outside of hiera.yaml of course)

Comment: Thanks for your answers
1) i don't have any hiera key starting with :
2) I did update the hiera.yaml file to have quotes likes this:
:backends: 
  - yaml

:hierarchy:
  - "client/%{clientcert}"
  - "roles/%{role}"
  - "environment/%{env}"
  - global
  
:yaml: 
  :datadir: /opt/puppet/hiera
  

3) My puppet version is 3.8.7 with Ruby 1.8.7 
I read that Ruby 1.8.7 doesn't have the function to_sym that hiera is using and I should upgrade to ruby 1.9.3 (but this cause a lot of issues with my puppet so I prefer not doing this)

Comment: puppet version: 3.8.7 
Ruby version: 1.8.7
hiera version: 1.3.4